# NuGet API not serving the latest version of a package

Tags: nuget

This is not the first time it has happened, so I assume it's a bug where in the pipeline of NuGet Client / Visual Studio / NuGet server. A package has just been updated on NuGet.org. The latest version is 3.0.0.14. When I went to upgrade my package it couldn't find it and it said I had the latest version. After using Fiddler to see what was going over the wire, it's clear the NuGet Server is not serving the latest information. This call returns version 3.0.0.13 as the latest version.

https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1/tweetmoasharp/index.json

Is that a bug on NuGet Server? Do they have a deliberate caching? Is it something the package publisher did that he didn't mark as a stable version?

Comment: Sounds like an HTTP Cache issue. Remember there are 2 hard problems in Computer Science, "Naming things", "Cache Invalidation" and "Off by one Errors"

Comment: I fear it! I was hoping someone new a magic workaround. :)

Comment: I can see the version 3.0.0.14 all over the place in the request. I also guess that it's some sort of cache issue you're having.

Comment: Yes, I can see it now too, but it took a couple of days for it to show up.